# Prove overflow checking expression is right

Tags: z3, smt

I have a C++ function that contains an expression (the overflow check) which is simply provable by hand. I have an optimization in mind, which seems right to me and I cannot find a counterexample to it, but I would like to be sure it is right. I heard about Z3 and it seems to be a perfect fit. I wrote a formula and Z3 said `unsat`, but the problem part is that I do not trust the results I get because I do not completely understand if I done the things right (the fear based on previous extraordinary results I got, but it was my fault and I recognized it).

The C++ function:

```
template <typename T>
bool add(int radix, int digit, T& n)
{
    assert(radix > 2);
    assert(radix <= 36);
    assert(digit >= 0);
    assert(digit < radix);

    T max = std::numeric_limits<T>::max();
    assert(max >= radix);

    // the overflows check
    if ((n > (max / radix)) || ((n * radix) > (max - digit)))
        return false;

    n = n * radix + digit;
    return true;
}
```

I want to prove (divisions are integer, no real part):

`(n > (max / radix)) || ((n * radix) > (max - digit))` <=> `n > ((max - digit) / radix)`

or more generally if those expressions always true when `(n * radix) > max` or `(n * radix + digit) > max`

Z3 code I have:

```
(declare-const radix Int)
(assert (>= radix 2))
(assert (<= radix 36)) ; this is the upper bound we officially support

(declare-const digit Int)
(assert (>= digit 0))
(assert (< digit radix))

(declare-const max Int)
(assert (> max 0))
(assert (>= max radix)) ; this is a reasonable requirement
;(assert (>= max 256)) ; the smallest upper bound for C++ fundamentals, but UDTs can have it lower

(declare-const n Int)
(assert (<= n max))
;(assert (>= n 0)) ; not really, but usually

; our current check
;(assert (not (or
;  (> n (div max radix))
;  (> (* n radix) (- max digit))
;)))
; our optimized check
(assert (not
  (> n (div (- max digit) radix))
))

(assert (or
  (> (* n radix) max)           ; check no mul overflow
  (> (+ n digit) max)           ; check no add overflow
  (> (+ (* n radix) digit) max) ; check no muladd overflow
))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
(exit)
```

https://rise4fun.com/Z3/po1h

Comment: A property which is valid for infinite-precision Ints is not necessarily valid for finite-precision int32_t, and vice versa. Is there any reason why you are not using Bit-Vectors, which correspond to machine-level integers? If you feel like you can't trust an unsat result, you may want to ask Z3 to produce an unsat-core (see tutorials online) that proves the unsat result. Does either overflow check really work for some combinations of negative values?

Comment: The former check will work for any integer, if a new one is equivalent to it - I am satisfied; the Z3 code I have posted contains checks for overflows (if I did it correctly). I want to have a proof for any integer precision of `n` because C++ fundamental types does not have exact representation, there can be compiler extensions with additional types like `__int128`, and also `n` can be a user defined type with its own bounds. I do not understand the last question, sorry, only the `n` variable can contain negative value.

Comment: It is exactly because you want to have a proof for machine integers that I would use the **Theory of Fixed-Size Bit-Vectors** and not the **Theory of Integers**. These theories have completely different properties and behaviour. What I was trying to ask is this: your test might prevent an overflow, but it seems to me that an underflow is still possible, [(e.g. n: -2147483647, r: 2, d: 0, for 32 bits)](https://codeshare.io/adx7Xe), why is this not tested?

Comment: I did not said in my previous comment because of the size limit: the case with negative `n` does not bother me because it does not have a meaning where it is used. This is the part of integer parser and `n` starts from zero, except when someone asked for accumulating parser and passed a negative value (there is negative accumulator parser for negative numbers and it handles underflow instead of overflow).

Comment: Strictly speaking, @PatrickTrentin (as is usual!) correct. It took me a while to recognize Nikita is checking all that is necessary explicitly, so I think the use of unbounded integers is correct here for the particular use case. But you can never be too careful! Also: I added note about overflow predicates to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks good to me. Stylistically, I would write it like the following:

```
(define-fun oldCheck () Bool
  (or (> n (div max radix)) 
      (> (* n radix) (- max digit))))

(define-fun newCheck () Bool
      (> n (div (- max digit) radix)))

(assert (distinct oldCheck newCheck))
```

which makes clear exactly what you are checking. You can rest assured that your optimization is good to go!

### A note on distinct

The `distinct` predicate is defined on page 37 of the SMTLib document: http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/papers/smt-lib-reference-v2.6-r2017-07-18.pdf

It is essentially equivalent to negated equivalence if you pass it precisely two arguments. However, the behavior is different for > 2 args: If you pass more arguments it ensures pairwise inequality. (That is, all of them must be different from each other.) It comes in quite handy in many problems.

Passing > 2 arguments to `=` is possible too, and it makes sure all the arguments are equal. But notice that when you have > 2 arguments, the negated equality and distinct become different: For instance, `2 2 3`, are not all equal, but they are not `distinct` either. I hope that makes it clear.

### A note on Overflow/Underflow checking

Patrick raised the issue of overflow checking and use of machine integers, and he is correct that one should worry about those cases. I think Nikita is already handling the particular use case here by ensuring explicit bounds. However, one cannot be too careful! For these purposes, z3 actually has overflow checking primitives built in. See this wonderful paper by Nikolaj on the details: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/z3prefix.pdf

The primitives z3 provides are:

- `bvsmul_noovfl`: Signed multiplication no overflow
- `bvsmul_noudfl`: Signed multiplication no underflow
- `bvumul_noovfl`: Unsigned multiplication no overflow

But see the paper on the logical formulas you can use to detect overflow for other operations. (Above three are rather complicated, so they are supported primitively. For other conditions, the checks can directly be done by the user.)

Comment: Great, thanks! Sorry for a question in comments, I cannot find `distinct` in documentation (it is used in examples, but there is no description), is it the same thing as writing `(not (= ...))`?

Comment: Added a note on `distinct` and overflow checking.